# UIAlertAction to pop to root view controller in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller, uialertaction

I am using Swift programming language and using `UIAlertController` with "Cancel" button to display alert. 
I'm using below code to create cancel button.

```
 let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: { (alert) -> Void in
    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
 })

 alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
```

On tapping "Cancel" button, user has to be taken back to root view controller.
But the code is not compiling. The error its showing is as below:

```
Cannot invoke 'init' with an argument list of type `(title: StringLiteralConvertible, style: UIActionSheetStyle, handler: (($T2) -> Void) -> Void)`
```

I couldn't understand how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer didn't work for me either; this one did. 
Add this function

```
func popToRoot() {
        self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

Then change the original function

```
{ (alert :UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
                self.popToRoot()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this.

```
 let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: 
          { action in 
             self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
          } )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing (alert) with:

`(alert :UIAlertAction!)`